# Web service using tomcat not working

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jersey

Actually i am completely new in web service development. I am unable to run simple dynamic web service application using eclipse oxygen, tomcat 7, jersey library. i know there is so many solutions are available i have tried but nothing is working for me, I am unable to find out where i am making mistake.

this is my class.

```
package book;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/book")
public class Book {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayHelloXML(){
    String response = "<?xml version='1.0'?>"+
            "<hello>Hello XML</hello>";
    return response;
}
}
```

this is web.xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>WSdemo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
<param-value>book</param-value>
</init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am getting some error but i am unable to resolve

```
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\sesatuser\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_144;;C:\Users\sesatuser\Desktop;;.
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WSdemo' did not find a matching property.
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1031 ms
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [152] milliseconds.
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:16 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sesatuser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\WSdemo\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:16 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\sesatuser\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\WSdemo\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/sesatuser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/WSdemo/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-api-1.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 07, 2017 1:35:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/sesatuser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/WSdemo/WEB-INF/lib/yasson-1.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 07, 2017 1:35:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/sesatuser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/WSdemo/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json.bind-api-1.0.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 07, 2017 1:35:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Users/sesatuser/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/WSdemo/WEB-INF/lib/javax.json-1.1.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 07, 2017 1:35:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 07, 2017 1:35:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9679 ms
```

I am using this url

```
http://localhost:8080/WSdemo/rest/book/sayHelloXML/
```

output in browser[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

The logs show that some dependencies are yet to be resolved (such as javax.json-api-1.1.jar, yasson-1.0.jar) Try adding those Jars in the Classpath. 
Moreover, you haven't provided the mapping '/sayHelloXML' for the function sayHelloXML().

Answer (score 0):

From this bug page : [Tomcat should skip or handle module-info.class when scanning for annotations](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=60688), you can see that the bug is the same :

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:...../javax.json-1.1.0-M1.jar] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
```

Job was in progress :

> Although Tomcat code can be updated independently of BCEL, we must
> know what the code "19" means and thus how many bytes to skip (for the
> simple case if it can be ignored).

and

> 19 is CONSTANT_Module and 20 is CONSTANT_Package.
>
> I don't see a reason to scan module-info for annotations at all.
> @WebServlet, @WebFilter, or @WebListener is not expected here anyway.

and

> Looks like we just need to skip 2 bytes. The change needs to be
> implemented in Commons BCEL first and then back-ported to Tomcat.

and finally the bug has been fixed in following versions :

> BCEL updated and back-port complete.
>
> Fixed in:
>
> - trunk for 9.0.0.M18 onwards
> - 8.5.x for 8.5.12 onwards
> - 8.0.x for 8.0.42 onwards
> - 7.0.x for **7.0.76** onwards

So if you want to stick to Tomcat 7, upgrade to at least version 7.0.76 .